# Use Samsung Galaxy Tab S Fingerprint Scanner to Login to app

Tags: samsung-mobile, fingerprint, samsung-mobile-sdk

Can I use the built in finger print scanner on my Galaxy Tab S to login to one of my apps? The user currently has to enter a username and password. Is there a way to link a finger print to this username/password? I don't want the user to login just if they have a fingerprint saved on the device... their finger print needs to correspond to a valid username/password for my app.

Answer (score 0):

With Samsung SDK you could only register 1 user, the user of device.

You could associate in your app, 1 one of app to the user of device.

After you could check current user with Pass SDK: http://developer.samsung.com/resources/pass

`SpassFingerprint` class has a method `startIdentify` : http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/pass/com/samsung/android/sdk/pass/SpassFingerprint.html#startIdentify(com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint.IdentifyListener)